# bash while read loop arguments from variable issue

Tags: bash, while-loop, ifs

I have a bash script with following variable:

```
operators_list=$'andrii,bogdan,eios,fre,kuz,pvm,sebastian,tester,tester2,vincent,ykosogon'

while IFS=, read -r tech_login; do


    echo "... $tech_login ..."

done <<< "$operators_list"
```

I need to read arguments from variable and work with them in loop. But it returns echo only one time with all items:

```
+ IFS=,
+ read -r tech_login
+ echo '... andrii,bogdan,eios,fre,kuz,pvm,sebastian,tester,tester2,vincent,ykosogon ...'
... andrii,bogdan,eios,fre,kuz,pvm,sebastian,tester,tester2,vincent,ykosogon ...
+ IFS=,
+ read -r tech_login
```

What am I doing wrong? How to rework script, so it will work only with one item per time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operators_list=$'andrii,bogdan,eios,fre,kuz,pvm,sebastian,tester,tester2,vincent,ykosogon'
```

So you have strings separated by `,`. You can do that multiple ways:

1. using bash arrays:

```
IFS=, read -a operators <<<$operators_list
for op in "${operators[@]}"; do
    echo "$op"
done
```

2. Using a while loop, like you wanted:

```
while IFS= read -d, -r op; do
    echo "$op"
done <<<$operators_list
```

3. Using xargs, because why not:

```
<<<$operators_list xargs -d, -n1 echo
```

The thing with IFS and read delimeter is: `read` reads until delimeter specified with `-d`. Then **after** `read` has read a full string (usually whole line, as default delimeter is newline), then the string is splitted into parts using `IFS` as delimeter. So you can:

```
while IFS=: read -d, -r op1 op2; do
    echo "$op1" "$op2"
done <<<"op11:op12,op12:op22"
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about -d, as delimiter!

Comment: note that the read exit status for last element is not 0, but could be handled : `while IFS= read -d, -r op; [[ $op ]]; do ...` but this would stop on first empty element otherwise `while IFS= read -d, -r op || [[ $op ]]; do ...`, howvwer for the last item would contain the final `\n` due to here string